# string trouble in c

Tags: c, string

The question is when I input a string with "sum" in begin and then compute the following number.

#### Input:

```
sum 10 20
```

#### Output:

```
30
```

but my code is wrong,the output is 33 (the processing is 11+22=33) 
I think that the second while loop has wrong ,but I don't know how to revise.

I need any master help.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char a[100];

    while (gets(a))
    {
        if (a[0] == 's'&&a[1] == 'u'&&a[2] == 'm')
        {
            int i;
            int sum = 0;

            for (i = 2; a[i]; i++){
                if (a[i] == ' '){
                    i++;
                    int num = 0;
                    while (1){
                        num += num * 10 + (a[i] - '0');
                        i++;
                        if (a[i] == ' ' || a[i]=='\0') break;
                    }
                    sum += num;
                    i--;
                }
            }

            printf("%d", sum);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `scanf`?

Comment: `scanf` is an unsafe and terrible method of parsing text, but yeah, it's better than what you have here. (IOW your approach is inherently non-scalable and will get out of hand in even most trivial cases).

Answer (score 2):

```
num += num * 10 + (a[i] - '0');
```

should be

```
num = num * 10 + (a[i] - '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

The double-counting occurs here:

```
num += num * 10 + (a[i] - '0');
```

For example with digits '12' you parse the 1, then ADD 12 to the 1 to get 13.  Change to:

```
num = num * 10 + (a[i] - '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `fgets`, `gets` is deprecated.  Secondly, I believe that you can reduce your code to half of its current size by making it a one-time program, but you can still easily start it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc != 3){
    printf("ERROR: Must input two integers!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  int first = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
  int second = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);

  int sum = first + second;

  printf("%d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

In this code I make use of `argc` and `argv`.  This means that on the command line, you can type `sum 10 20` and it will pass in 10 and 20 as arguments.  The second thing I use is `strtol`, this converts a string (10 and 20 start off as strings) into a `long int`.

And you should use GDB.  it is the Gnu DeBugger.  Look it up.

Comment: Mior: this solution silently converts from `long` to `int` with `int first = strtol(...)` with possible loss of of data.

Comment: In 2014 my gcc running on a 64-bit platform uses 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long` and embedded processor uses 16-bit `int` and 32-bit `long`.  "at this point in time all `int`s are `long` ints" may be your experience but its it not so in general practice nor is that supported by the C11 spec which obliges `int` at least 16 bit and long at least 32 bit.

Comment: however, `long int` is pretty much and obsolete term, like `signed int`, if you really want to ensure a type match, make `first`, `second`, and `sum` `int32_t` and `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: `long` is certainly not obsolete.  Suggest posting an SO question "Is `long` is an obsolete term?" if there is doubt.  Using a fixed width integer type does have its place, yet the same conversion issue remains: `int32_t first = strtol(...)` with possible loss of of data.  Note: C specifies that fixed width integer types are in `<stdint.h>`

Comment: `long` is _not_ specified to be 32 bit.  This may be your experience, but that is not the C specification.  C spec implies it must be at _least_ 32-bit ("... Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign. ... minimum value for an object of type long int  LONG_MIN -2147483647 ... maximum value for an object of type long int LONG_MAX +2147483647 ..." C11 §5.2.4.2.1 1.)  gcc, as mentioned earlier on my, PC is 64-bit.

Comment: It would probably be best to just make `sum` and all those the biggest your system supports; thus `int64_t` since `gcc` can actually do 64 bit number on 32 bit systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66597/discussion-between-chux-and-gophyr).